# QPoint for context menu position

Tags: python, pyqt, contextmenu

I generate these i buttons:

```
self.connect(self.ui.pushButton_i, QtCore.SIGNAL('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint)'), self.on_context_menu)
```

The buttons are paced in a `gridLayout`. The position of the `contextMenu` horizontal is OK but the vertical position is always on the lowest of the buttons.

How can I make sure the contextMenu postion is just right below the cursor (the standaard position) ?

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to ask the object that creates the `contextMenu` to map the mouse coordinate to a global coordinate:

```
      self.editorContextMenu.exec_(self.confEditorTree.mapToGlobal(point))
```

Here `editorContextMenu` being the the `contextMenu` itself and `self.confEditorTree` being the thing that was clicked on. So in you're case you might have to ask the `pushButtons` to map the mouse coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, but I have this already:
     def on_context_menu(self, point):
        # show context menu
        self.popMenu.exec_(self.ui.pushButton_i.mapToGlobal(point))